# Expect: Remove color code from sailsjs v0.12.13 logs

Tags: node.js, logging, sails.js

I have worked on Sails v0.11.5 and used colors:false in development.js to get clean log without color codings

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logDir = '/var/log/nginx';
var applicationLogger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            level: 'info',
            filename: logDir + '/application.log'
        })
    ]
});
module.exports = {
    log: {
        colors: false, // To get clean logs without prefixes or color codings
        custom: applicationLogger
    }
};
```

Now I am working on Sails v0.12.13 and using same configuration colors:false but this time I am getting color codes in log

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logDir = '/var/log/nginx';
var applicationLogger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            level: 'info',
            filename: logDir + '/application.log'
        })
    ]
});
module.exports = {
    log: {
        colors: false, // To get clean logs without prefixes or color codings
        custom: applicationLogger
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about how this attribute was defined in Sails v0.11.5, but I guess you should try using **colorize** instead of **colors**

```
module.exports = {
    log: {
        colorize: false, // To get clean logs without prefixes or color codings
        custom: applicationLogger
    }
};
```

Please tell me if I am missing something with this attribute.

**Edit**

Seems colors attribute is part of built-in logger called captains-log, maybe your custom logger winston is overriding these changes, can you check the changes and tell if my answer worked for you?